# complexity of combinatorial function

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, combinatorics

How the complexity of an algorithm involved with combinatorial operations is classified.

Let's say the input is m, n, and the complexity is determined by C(m,n). (C is the combination function of choosing m from n). The question is how the complexity should be categorized instead of just giving C(m,n).

I mean, to give an idea of the running time of an algorithm, you can say the algorithm is of polynomial, exponential time complexity. But what to do with C(m,n) ?

I know factorials can be approximated by using [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but the result is still too complex to put it in a complexity class.

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on retaining both m and n, then it's going to be hard to do better than Stirling's approximation. The upper bound for m alone is C(m, m/2), which is asymptotic to 2<sup>m</sup>/√m and thus exponential.

Comment: Isn't it (2^m)√m (√m in the numerator, not denominator)?

Comment: @Ted Hopp No – there are only 2^m subsets.

Comment: C(m, m/2) ≈ m! / ((m/2)!)^2 ~ (m^m / √m) / ((n/2)^(n-1)) ~ (2^m)√m. Note that O(2^m) ≠ O((2^m) √m). I just don't see how you got O((2^m) / √m).

Comment: @Ted Hopp Stirling's formula is n! ~ √(2πn) (n/e)^n. You put the surd in the denominator.

Comment: Yes, you do. But for C(m, m/2) the denominator is squared and when you apply Stirling's formula to the ratio, the _squared_ surd in the denominator ends up in the numerator (with another surd in the denominator).

Comment: @Ted Hopp No, the squared surd starts in the numerator and ends up in the denominator. Stirling's formula is sufficiently accurate that I have no idea why you think your answer could be correct.

Comment: https://www.moderndescartes.com/essays/2n_choose_n/ for those who want to get into the math behind the estimation

Answer (score 1):

You can't "put it into a complexity class" because it isn't a single-variable running time.

It's "asymptotic behaviour" is undefined, because which variable should we consider to approach infinite? Even if we said both approach infinite `lim {n->inf, m->inf} nCm` is undefined because their relative values are undefined. I.e. the behaviour depends not just on `n` and `m` being greater than a certain value, but their relative values as well.

The complexity depends on two variables, and `nCm` is a perfectly valid complexity function.

If you have a reasonable approximation for `m` relative to `n` then you can class it more easily. Maybe it's worthwhile working out cases, where `m = O(n)`, `m = O(1)`.
Or where `m = [kn]` and  `0 <= k <= 1` is constant + Stilring's formula, gives you a nice relation in one variable while still being able to consider values of `m` relative to `k`.

Comment: As @spartan pointed out, `nCm` has a maximum in `m` at `n/2`. Also, `m <= n` so `m` cannot approach infinitely independently of `n`.

Comment: @Ted, Indeed you can give a gross `O(2^n)` by taking the maximum, but if `m` is `inverseAckerman(n)` for example, then we've overestimated essentially a linear runtime to an exponential one. So while the maximum exists, it often isn't useful. As per your second point, there are obviously constraints on `m`, I never suggested otherwise, but even under the constraints everything I said is true, and the limit is undefined. As to your wording, I'm not sure what it means to be "infinitely independent" of n.

Comment: that was a typo. It was supposed to say "cannot approach infinity independent of `n`".

Comment: @Ted, well in that case I contest that `m` can definitely approach infinity independent of `n`, despite having the constraint `m <= n`. `lim {n->inf, m->inf} ...` gives you no relation between `n` and `m`, and so their relative growths is undefined/unknown. Although if you were merely pointing out that there is a constraint on `m`, then there is nothing to contest.

Comment: @david - I guess we have different definitions of "independent". Certainly `m` is not statistically independent of `n` and the half plane `m <= n` is not the entire plane. But I take your point that `m` need not be large merely because `n` is.